# Firebase: Create FIFO Inventory to get value

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been stuck with this problem for a month.

I've been trying to use firebase to create a FIFO Inventory. I am using firebase cloud function to update the FIFO inventory. However if I stress test the following code just 10 times with for loop for both insert (push) and remove (pop), it breaks because of the concurrent update.

**Does anyone have another solution for this?**

Insert FIFO/PUSH:

```
let fifoRef = admin.database().ref('fifo/' + item.itemId + '/').push();
let fifo = {
    price: data.items[uniqueId].price,
    in: data.items[uniqueId].quantity,
    quantity: data.items[uniqueId].quantity,
}
fifoRef.set(fifo);
```

Get FIFO Value/POP (Here I simply update the quantity for POP):

```
// get fifo
let fifoReference = 'fifo/' + item.itemId;
let fifoRef = admin.database().ref(fifoReference);
fifoRef.once('value').then(currentData => {
  let fifo = currentData.val();

  for (let key in fifo) {
    let val = fifo[key];

    if (val.quantity > 0) {
    // get fifo quantity
    let fifoQuantityRef = admin.database().ref(fifoReference + '/' + key + '/quantity/');

    // get local cache value
    let fifoQuantityListener = fifoQuantityRef.on('value', () => {                                      
      // transaction start
      fifoQuantityRef.transaction(function (quantity) {
        if (quantity) {
          if (quantity > 0 && quantitySubtotal > 0) {

            if (quantity >= quantitySubtotal) {
              // minus inventory amount
              let amount = calculator(quantitySubtotal + "*" + val.price);

              quantity = calculator(quantity + "-" + quantitySubtotal);
              quantitySubtotal = 0;

              // update quantity
              return quantity;
            } else {
              let amount = calculator(quantity + "*" + val.price);

              quantitySubtotal = calculator(quantitySubtotal + "-" + quantity);
              return 0;
            }
          }
        }
        return quantity;
      }, (error, committed, result) => {
        fifoQuantityRef.off('value', fifoQuantityListener);
    }, true);
  });
```

Brainstorming:
I just need Insight on how to get the VALUE using FIFO. From my understanding Firebase is best used to insert and remove not with transaction. But if I am using only insert and remove, how to create a FIFO? If I create FIFO with the quantity of 1, the data stored will be too large.

I did try to use Google Datastore, however datastore persistence is extremely slow (over 2 seconds for writing). Which is not possible to be used with firebase which have persistence of less than 1 second. The problem arise when PUSH and POP is done within 1 seconds, datastore insert is not persisted yet.

**Any other brainstorming ideas?**

Comment: Sorry, but this code is quite hard to understand. Why are you nesting a transaction inside a listener on the same location? `let fifoQuantityListener = fifoQuantityRef.on('value', () => {  fifoQuantityRef.transaction(function (quantity) {`. It probably doesn't cause problems, but it convolutes the code. It also would be good to know what breaks about the code. Any error messages?

Comment: The transaction will always returns null because of an empty local cache. So, the on method creates the local cache.